# Make sum of an Object values

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an Object and I need to make sum of the result.
For the example I have 2 array with 4 object each.
I need to make sum of the result of the objects who have range_of_test between 400 and 700.
I want to exclude the results of the range_of_test [700-800]

A the end, I need to sum all these results in variable result_of_test

https://codepen.io/czechsebastian/pen/JjdMMKJ?editors=1011

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        { result: 1.205281224980167, range_of_test: [400, 500] },
        { result: 1.3752106835385345, range_of_test: [500, 600] },
        { result: 1.9558246742225325, range_of_test: [600, 700] },
        { result: 0.6175274642830954, range_of_test: [700, 800] },
        { result: 0.6327715359706052, range_of_test: [400, 500] },
        { result: 0.7219843456204036, range_of_test: [500, 600] },
        { result: 1.0268061573906662, range_of_test: [600, 700] },
        { result: 0.32420135150190965, range_of_test: [700, 800] },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    result_of_test() {
      return null;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a computed property for calculate this:

See the code below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        { result: 1.205281224980167, range_of_test: [400, 500] },
        { result: 1.3752106835385345, range_of_test: [500, 600] },
        { result: 1.9558246742225325, range_of_test: [600, 700] },
        { result: 0.6175274642830954, range_of_test: [700, 800] },
        { result: 0.6327715359706052, range_of_test: [400, 500] },
        { result: 0.7219843456204036, range_of_test: [500, 600] },
        { result: 1.0268061573906662, range_of_test: [600, 700] },
        { result: 0.32420135150190965, range_of_test: [700, 800] },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    result_of_test() {
      let result = 0;
      for (let item of this.list) {
        let incorrectRange = item.range_of_test.filter(range => range < 400 || range > 700);
        if (incorrectRange.length == 0) {
          result += item.result;
        }
      }
      return result;
    },
  },
});
```

PS: I corrected somethings in your code.

Answer of your question:
If you want to sum just of the range [400, 500] or [700, 800], you can do this way:

```js
...
  computed: {
    result_of_test() {
      let result = 0;
      for (let item of this.list) {
        let [first, second] = item.range_of_test;
        if (
          (first == 400 && second == 500) ||
          (first == 700 && second == 800)
        ) {
          result += item.result;
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Great, can you tell me How I do to just make the sum of the range [400, 500] or [700, 800} ?

Comment: Yes, is possible. I update my answer. This is what you want?

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people.
[How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
[Why accept an answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Created computed property like :

```
  computed: {
    result_of_test() {
        return this.list.reduce((currentValue, item) => {
           if((item.range_of_test[0] >= 400 && item.range_of_test[1] <= 800) && !(item.range_of_test[0] >= 700 && item.range_of_test[1] <= 800)){
              return currentValue + item.result
           }
        return currentValue;
    }, 0)
  }
```